# Makefile, Run environment check target before user run any targets

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile

I want to run following environment check target `checkenv` before any of other targets,

```
all: build_sub_target1 build_target2
clean: clean_sub_target1 clean_target2
...
...

checkenv:
    $(if $(PROJECT_ROOT), , \
      $(error $(shell echo -e '\033[41;33mFATAL: Please load project settings first. \
        Run "source PROJECT_ROOT_DIR/envsetup.sh"\033[0m')) \
    )
```

I want every other target run `checkenv` target before they actually do their task, how can I do this? Any other way except that I add `checkenv` to the depends list of each targets?
Since I have many targets in this file, and I think it's not cool to add into each targets... Should there be any potential rules to do this?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [make conditionals](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-ifndef-562) for that, so that this condition is checked while the makefile is being read and before targets get evaluated:

```
ifndef PROJECT_ROOT
$(error "Please load project settings first. Run source PROJECT_ROOT_DIR/envsetup.sh")
endif
```

Comment: Yes, it's good way to do this. This kind of task doesn't need to make a target.